# What's the difference between textField delegate and using textSignal in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, delegates, reactive-cocoa

I want to know, what is the difference between using textField delegate `textDidChange` and

```
nameTextField.rac_textSignal().subscribeNext { (input) -> Void in 
        print(input) 
}
```

? Can anyone help me to understand the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question, and I think there's not a lot changes between these two patterns.

If you have multiple outlets of the same type with delegates, and you want to use it for at least 2 of them, you have to differentiate them so you can add a condition in your delegate method. With reactive this is not the case because you act on an outlet object directly.

You can use reactive for that if you already implement a reactive library for other behaviors, or if you just want to improve your skills with this pattern. Otherwise, I would not recommend using, it will just increase your app size.

PS: this is just my personal opinion, I'm not really familiar with reactive, but this seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Signals *multicast*, take blocks as observers, and do not require a concrete type to conform to the delegate. You can also compose signals using operators, say `take(until: trigger)` to limit the lifetime of the signal.

After all, these kind of frameworks are meant to be declarative and expressive, and help you maintain your app architecture and reason your codes better.